# Como ocultar todos os botões com foreach?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Segue código:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button_1).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
```

O código acima é para ocultar um "botão 1" e tenho mais de 50 botões. Não quero copiar toda essa linha e fazer até 50 vezes, é muito cansativo. Existe uma forma de fazer um loop usando `foreach` ou `for` para ocultar todos esses botões  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em um pergunta com uma dúvida semelhante, surgiu a seguinte solução:

```
ViewGroup group = findViewById(R.id.root); // The name of your layout
int children = group.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {

    View child = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof ViewOne) {        
       ... 
    } else if (child instanceof ViewTwo) {
       ...
    }
}
```

No qual você pega um layout raiz (que contém os seus botões) e consegue iterar sobre eles.
No seu caso ficaria algo como:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.root);
int children = viewGroup.ChildCount;
for (int i = 0; i < children; i++)
{
    string buttonID = "btn" + i;
    int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(buttonID, "id", PackageName);
    FindViewById<Button>(resID).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184889/android-refer-to-custom-views-in-a-loop/4185818#4185818